# IE compatibility mode forced when using internal ip

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5

Im working a web app in asp.net, using ajax and jQuery, and C# as the programming language on VS2010. The prod server is a 2008 R2 and users use Internet Explorer 9 (cant use Chrome or other) on Win7 PCs.

My issue is that users are seeing my webpage in compatibility mode in IE causing the update panels to stop working, inserts are not showed, cascade drop-downs doesn't update and CSS rounded corners doesn't show.

If users access the site via the external domain everything works great, but most users doesnt have access to internet and use the internal IP, then theres when the issue shows up.

How can I make the site open in normal mode when users use the internal IP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in head section of html document this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow, base on the documentation it should work. Thanks for the replay.